# Custom tag namespace implementation in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, dtd

For an audio player I'm building, I'd like to have a tag similar to what Google and Facebook use for their share widgets. For example, it could be:

```
<fp:player data-type="mp3" data-href="/path/to/file.mp3" />
```

What's the best way to implement this custom tag, and have it be valid in as many browsers as possible?

Comment: Could you perhaps convert the <fp:player ... /> tag on the server side into valid HTML before sending it to the client? Or do you specifically want that tag in your source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#extensibility):

> For markup-level features that are intended for use with the HTML syntax, extensions should be limited to new attributes of the form "x-vendor-feature", where vendor is a short string that identifies the vendor responsible for the extension, and feature is the name of the feature. **New element names should not be created**

So you can't create it and conform to the specification and Facebook and Google are very, very naughty.

You appear to be trying to reinvent [the `<audio>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-audio-element) anyway. So just use that and the problem of extending the langage goes away.

Comment: Not reinventing `<audio>`, I'm making a generic tag for several types of audio embeds.

Comment: `<audio>` is a generic tag for several types of audio embeds.

Comment: I'm choosing this answer because it clarifies that new element names should not be created.

Answer (score 3):

The above-linked specification **also** states,

> User agents must treat elements and attributes that they do not
>   understand as semantically neutral; leaving them in the DOM (for DOM
>   processors), and styling them according to CSS (for CSS processors),
>   but not inferring any meaning from them.

Quentin's posted quote, if I understand the specification correctly, is referring to user-agent extensions. (By which I assume they mean both special browsers and browser plugins.) **User-agents** should not create new tags or attributes. **Web developer** can use whatever made-up tags and attributes they like. And the specification explicitly instructs user-agent  developers to account for unknown tags and attributes, and include them in the DOM and when rendering the page.

Accessing them with script is where it becomes a little tricky. IE's 7 and 8 for you to add a namespace to find those custom tags, which makes your document technically invalid -- ***but still fully functional!***

See here (my blog): http://blog.svidgen.com/2012/10/building-custom-xhtml5-tags.html

Comment: The user was asking about *valid* markup. As you note, it is "technically" invalid. You can hack things to make it work, but that does not mean you should.

Comment: Also note that it is required for you to disclose that you are linking to *your own blog*; a fact which makes its use as a reference for your answer quite suspect.

Comment: I've edited above to note that it's my blog. And yes, I understand the concern for validity, hence explicitly spelling out point at which the code becomes invalid (adding a namespace). My concern, however, was the hasty, incomplete manner of the first (chosen) answer, which suggests that custom tags are off limits for *developers*, which isn't quite what the specification states. The specification actually states the opposite. It's only in introducing a hack to force IE's 7 and 8 into compliance that it becomes invalid -- but still functional.

Comment: ... the selected answer was simply incomplete and misleading, IMO. And I'm sorry, I didn't realize linking to a related article I wrote required me to explicitly note it. I figured it was obvious by my screenname!

Comment: Understood! Not everyone looks too closely at the URLs to see such items, so this just makes it very clear. That's a great edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

observe how the html5shim or the html5shiv create new elements: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv.js

essentially you just have to document.createElement() the element, then you can use it.